# Update view based on new object property?

Tags: ember.js

I have an each loop in my template that iterates over the tiles to the page.

Within each tile I have a button initially set to show the text "select me" within the button.

When the button is clicked I simply want to be able to set a property named 'selected' to the tiles object and set it to true when the action button is clicked so that the text on the button changes to "unselect me".

Only one of the tiles can have selected: true at any given time. The others can be to false.

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

//Items
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return tiles;
    }
});

App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({

    actions: {
        productClick: function(id){

            var tile = tiles.findBy('id', id);

            tile.set('selected', true);
        }
    }
});

var tiles = [
    {
        id: '1',
        title: 'tile 1'
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        title: 'tile 2'
    },
    {
        id: '3',
        title: 'tile 3'
    }
];
```

templates:

```
  <!--Index page-->
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <div class="tile-wrapper">
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Test</h1>
      </div>

      {{outlet}}
    </div>
  </script>

  <!--Tiles-->
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
    <div class="row">
      {{#each}}
        {{partial 'tile'}}
      {{/each}}
    </div>

    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <!--Tile partial-->
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="_tile">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <p>{{title}}</p>


        <button {{action "productClick" id target="view"}}>
          {{#if selected}}
            unselect me
          {{else}}
            select me
          {{/if}}
        </button>


      </div>
    </div>
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the state of the selected item and create a computed property in your view component which compares if the view content is selected or not.

```
App.IndexController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  selected: null,
  actions: {
     productClick: function(title){
       this.set('selected', title);
     }
  }

});

App.SelectButtonComponent = Em.Component.extend({

  isSelected: Em.computed(function() {
    return this.get('content') === this.get('selected');
  }).property('content', 'selected'),

  click: function() {

    this.sendAction('action', this.get('content'));

  }
});


  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/select-button">
          {{#if isSelected}}
            unselect me 
          {{else}}
            select me
          {{/if}}
  </script>

  {{select-button tagName='button' action="productClick"
    content=item  selected=selected}}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zicib/1/edit

Comment: I modified the fiddle to allow unselecting a title as well. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yasuf/1/edit

Comment: Am I missing something? Neither of these jsbins work.

Comment: @Malcr001, the problem could be that CDN was not fetching the JS dependiencies. Both jsbin works.

Comment: Is there a reason a Component was created? Does it need to be like that?

Comment: @Malcr001, No, you could also use a Ember.View, but I think, the implementation would differ from the component. Normally, it's a general good practice to use components for isolated and reusable views.