# How do I get clicked elements model in View - Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a view with number of divs in rows. When I click on a div the current clicked element should be selected. Below is the code I have used.

```
{{#each}} 
    <div {{action target="view" on="click" allowedKeys="shift"}} {{bind-attr class=':user isActive'}} > 
        {{test}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

My view is backed by a model as:

```
model: function() { 
    return [{'test':'1'}, {'test' :'2'}, {'test': '3'}, {'test': '4'}]; 
}
```

In my view I handled the click handler.

```
click: function( e ) { 
    if( e.shiftKey ){
        this.modelFor("index").send('changeBgSelection', {'test' :'2'} ); // Here I could not get the current clicked elements model.
    }

    // Here I need to get the current clicked elements model. When I click the second element I need to get as  "{'test' :'2'}". But I could not get the current elements model. Instead I can get the whole model.

}
```

In my Route,
Here the clicked element is made active.

```
actions:{
    changeBgSelection: function (params) { 
        var select = this.get("controller").objectAt(this.modelFor("index").indexOf(params)); 
        select.set('isActive', true)
    }
}
```

So how do I get the current clicked elements model in my View? So that I can pass the model to my Route to make the clicked div active with Shift key is pressed.

Edited: Jsbin [Link](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yawewayu/4/edit)

Comment: You could pass the context in your action as {{action "edit" this target="view"}}. It would be easier understand and help you if you prepare a http://emberjs.jsbin.com/

Comment: @ppcano I have updated the jsbin link.

Comment: I think, your case could be a duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23656751/update-view-based-on-new-object-property/23658167, I gave a response with a JSBin where it gives a solution for your case.

Comment: @ppcano The above link is not the duplication of my question. I am handling the click event with shift key pressed, also I need to handle on Control key press.

Comment: are you trying to accomplish the same use case which it is to show a list of items where an item could be selected? In my example, I show another way to make it work, then you could easily change when the action is send by checking the state of e.shiftKey and ctrlKey. Anyway, the response below seems also to work.

Comment: @ppcano As I send in my previous comment, I need to select the element  with the following combinations of actions, click, shift+click, ctrl+click. Your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/23658167/320097 , how will you get the event so that I can trigger my selection method when the combination of click in handled.

Comment: click: function(e) {
    if (e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey)  this.sendAction('action', this.get('content'));
  }

Comment: @ppcano I could not get the content from my view. I am not using any Component. I could not get the content(current clicked elements model) even when I set it in my view.

Comment: This is a different problem, you do need to use Component to pass a object to an ember view.  The response below provides an example passing a content param to the view which is accessed on the click method, you should do exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to respond to a mouse click in Ember:

- Call an action
- Handle it in a view

It seems you tried to combine the two and it became a mess. I'm sure there's a way to make it work, but I can't find it. Instead, allow me to propose an alternative.

In general, if there's something fancy going on with javascript or event handling (like the SHIFT key in your example), I like to deal with it in a localized view. Here, each 'TestView' is tied to a single model instance, which it manipulates based on user input.

```html
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    {{#each}}
      {{#view App.TestView content=this}}
        {{this.test}}
      {{/view}}
    {{/each}}
  </script>
```

```js
App = Ember.Application.create();

function wrap(ob) {
  return Ember.Object.create(ob);
}

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return [
      wrap({'test':'1', 'isActive':false}),
      wrap({'test' :'2', 'isActive':false}),
      wrap({'test': '3', 'isActive':false}),
      wrap({'test': '4', 'isActive':false})
    ];
  }
});

App.TestView = Ember.View.extend({
  classNames: ["user"],
  classNameBindings: ["content.isActive:is-active"],
  click: function(e) { 
    if (e.shiftKey) {
      this.get("content").toggleProperty("isActive");
    }
  }
});
```

This can be cleaned up some more, but you get the gist. Live demo [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yawewayu/7/edit).

Comment: @panta83 Thanks for your reply. One doubt how will I handle the same action when control key is pressed? I tried to get the control key event but it always returns false. Where can I use allowedKeys in my view?

Comment: If you need it just in combo with mouse click, you can test with `if (e.ctrlKey)`. If you need to detect it independently, you first need to add tabindex (so the element would accept key focus), then add one of the event hooks found [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#toc_event-names). Working demo [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yawewayu/17/edit).

Comment: e.ctrlKey always returns false when I click crtlKey and click the div. My requirement is to select the div when ctrlKey is pressed and clicked.

Comment: It should not be: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yawewayu/19/edit. Tested in all 3 browsers.

Comment: e.ctrlKey always returns false I have tested in all browsers, I am using MAC.

Comment: Maybe it's the ctrl/mac/option confusion on mac? Either way, this is more to do with jquery than ember.